# autopopulate dynamically a dropdown menu with filename in a folder

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a folder in my local server with files inside, I would like a dropdown menu that can show me the names of the files with the correct extension (php). I think I wrote the right php code but I don't know how to call it properly. The folder I want the dropdown menu to take the files name is in /dashboard/scenario

Here is my HTML

```
<script type="text/php">

  $file_matcher = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/../scenario/       
  *.{pentestrc}';

  foreach( glob($file_matcher, GLOB_BRACE) as $file ) {
  $file_name = basename($file);
  $select .= "<option value='$file'>$file_name</option>\n";
  }

  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
   }
  window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

  var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
  }
  }
  }
  }

  </script>


  <div class="dropdown">
  <button style="margin-left: 43em;" onclick="myFunction()" 
  class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div style="margin-left: 43em;"id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-
  content">
  <a href="<?= $select ?>">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
  </div>
```